# Permissions error when calling createEntityType

Tags: node.js, permissions, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm attempting to call `createEntityType` from the [`dialogflow`](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2) [node.js](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjK--rY7c3XAhVlIMAKHTqaA8MQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnodejs.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw1tY2p-vJFWJmxWlq4sTxCn) library, and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Failed to create size entity type: { Error: IAM permission 'dialogflow.entityTypes.create' on 'projects/My-Project-Name/agent' denied.
    at /home/my/path/to/My-Project-Name/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
  code: 7,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: { 'grpc-server-stats-bin': [Array] } } }
```

This is after I've worked through the tutorial on enabling the [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials), which appears to have worked for the most part.

I've tried enabling all of the IAM Permissions for the associated account on the Google Cloud Platform, but this hasn't resolved the issue; these all seem related to the [Google App Engine](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwyPXI7c3XAhUlM8AKHRaGC14QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.google.com%2Fappengine%2F&usg=AOvVaw0Z-fLkFyHD-VxyRwexMF4k). Is there somewhere I can go to manipulate DialogFlow-specific IAM permissions?

Comment: how are you passing the credential. Is it possible for you share your snippet of your code for authorization??

Comment: `const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient({'keyFilename' : './keys.json'});` and `const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient({'keyFilename' : './keys.json'});` and have tried both developer and admin access and even the name of project is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I wasn't declaring the application name properly.

In the `createEntityType` [example](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/tree/master/samples), you're required to use the method `intentsClient.projectAgentPath(...)` to define the URI of your project agent.

Although the high-level name of my project consists of capital letters, the the actual Project ID does not; and it is this that the Cloud SDK attempts to verify against.  Therefore, when calling `projectAgentPath(...)`, use the **exact** Project ID specified in your Agent's [settings](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#settings).

In addition, ensure that the DialogFlow API is enabled for your project. You can do this by visiting the URL below:

`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/dialogflow.googleapis.com/?project=my-project-name`